# SQL Case statement not giving the desired result

Tags: sql-server, case

I am working on a sql case statement. I have the following departments:
Dept: 'SCV', 'ICT', 'SCM', 'MTH', 'AAT', 'ACC', 'GCSE'

```
Here's my case statement:

CASE WHEN Dept = 'MTH' AND Course.Name Like 'Func%' THEN 'MTH Func'
            WHEN Dept = 'MTH' AND Course.Name Like 'GCSE%' THEN 'MTH GCSE' 
      ELSE Dept END AS Department
```

Here's my result set:
[image: My result set]

I don't want MTH in my result set. Please help.

Comment: What should it be?  By the way, this is a `case` *expression* not a `case` statement.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. I want to see all the departments and where it is MTH I want it to be 2 separate departments MTH Func and MTH GCSE.

Comment: In the `ELSE` section put what you want to get (like `'ABC'`) and not the `Dept`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture remove "MTH", then you need a condition for that.  You clearly have courses that are not like "Func" or GCSE" in the MTH department.

Perhaps you want:

```
(CASE WHEN Dept = 'MTH' AND Course.Name Like 'Func%' THEN 'MTH Func'
      WHEN Dept = 'MTH' AND Course.Name Like 'GCSE%' THEN 'MTH GCSE' 
      WHEN Dept = 'MTH' THEN 'Anything but MTH' 
      ELSE Dept
 END) AS Department
```

Or perhaps you want:

```
(CASE WHEN Dept = 'MTH' AND Course.Name Like 'Func%' THEN 'MTH Func'
      WHEN Dept = 'MTH' THEN 'MTH GCSE' 
      ELSE Dept
 END) AS Department
```